# Angular: ngOnInit don't load my function?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngoninit

I need your help please

I would like to load myFunction when my page is load with ngOnInit().
But it's don't work.

```
.
.
myData: any = [];
.
.
.
ngOnInit()
{
    this.myFunction();
}

myFunction()
{
    return this.restApi.getMydata().subscribe((data: {}) => {
    this.myData = data;
}
```

I try to put a button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn" value = "submit" (click) = "myFunction()" >test</button>
```

And it work.

Why ngOnInit() don't load it ?

If you could help me, Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think it should work, would you please provide a working example ?

Comment: Could you please clarify what are you trying to accomplish here? From the outset, closing brackets `});` is missing in your subscription.

Comment: How do you know that it don't load? Did you try to put console.log at the beginning of myFunction?